# Nilpotent matrices and rank reducing

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was wondering if this was true or not.

> Suppose I have a square matrix  $M$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ such that Rank$(M)>\; $Rank$(M^2)$. Is it true that then $M$ is nilpotent?

I think this is true, but I could be wrong. Can someone confirm. Thanks.

Comment: If $M$ is in a finite dimensional space, then the rank of some power of $M$ will eventually reduce to zero, because of the relation above. Then that power of $M$ will be identically zero, so $M$ seems nilpotent to me. On the other hand, I think for infinite dimensional spaces, a counterexample can be found.

Comment: It can be shown that [every matrix is the sum of a nilpotent and diagonalizable part](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157625/every-nxn-matrix-is-the-sum-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix-and-a-nilpotent-matrix).  Diagonalizable matrices preserve rank, so whatever rank reducing matrix you have must be a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: Ok I take back what I said. $rank M > rank M^2$ does not imply that $rank M^2 > rank M^4$. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not true.

The rank may *stabilize* -- and in turn, the kernel will stabilize, too.

The operator may or may not be nilpotent.

Something that you can search for, for further reading, is something called "The Fitting Decomposition".

This is especially important stuff, when learning the Jordan Canonical Form of a matrix.

One last note:  the rank (and kernel) will *always* stabilize in a *finite-dimensional* vector space -- this is obvious, after learning about the fitting decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M = \pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}$

$M^2 = \pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$

$rank(M)>rank(M^2)$ and $M^2 = M^3 = M^n$