# Can all matrices be written as the sum of commuting matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Can all matrices be written as the sum of commuting matrices?

All invertible matrices $A$ can be written as a sum of matrices $A=B+C$ such that $B$ and $C$ commute, $BC=CB$.

One example might be $$B=\frac{A+A^{-1}}{2}, \quad C=\frac{A-A^{-1}}{2},$$ but I'm not certain if this is the only solution.

My question is:

**Can non-invertible matrices be written as the sum of commuting matrices?**

Edit: In response to Lulu's comment, I need to add another condition that neither of $B$ or $C$ commute with all matrices.

Comment: Well, $A=A+0$ and $A,0$ commute.  More broadly, if $C$ is any matrix that commutes with every matrix then $A=(A-C)+C$.  Are there more conditions?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157625)

Comment: @lulu I seem to have overlooked that option! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I suppose I should add the requirement that one of the matrices does not commute with all matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is negative in the following two pathological cases:

1. When the matrices are $1\times1$, the answer is negative because all matrices commute.
2. When $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix over $GF(2)$ and it is not a scalar matrix, the answer is also negative. In this case, $A$ is similar to either $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ or a companion matrix. Therefore $A$ only commutes with polynomials in itself. Now, in order that $B$ commutes with $C=A-B$, we must have $AB=BA$. Hence $B$ must be a polynomial in $A$. So, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $B=pA+qI_2$ and $C=A-B=(1-p)A-qI_2$ for some scalars $p,q\in GF(2)=\{0,1\}$. But then one of $B$ or $C$ will be a scalar matrix that commutes with all matrices.

In all other cases, the answer to your question is affirmative.

If $A$ is a scalar matrix whose size is at least $2\times2$, i.e., if $A=aI_n$ for some $n\ge2$, we may take $B=\operatorname{diag}(b,a,\ldots,a)$ and $C=\operatorname{diag}(a-b,0,\ldots,0)$ for any $b\ne a$.

If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, its size is at least $2\times2$ and the field is not $GF(2)$, we may simply take $B=pA$ and $C=(1-p)A$ for any $p\not\in\{0,1\}$.

If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, its size is at least $3\times3$ and the field is $GF(2)$, there are two possibilities:

1. $A$ can be diagonalised as $aI_k\oplus(1-a)I_{n-k}$ where $2\le k<n$. Then we may take $B=(1-a)\oplus aI_{k-1}\oplus (1-a)I_{n-k}$ and $C=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)$.
2. $A$ is not diagonalisable. Its minimal polynomial is then at least quadratic. If it is at least cubic, then $A-A^2$ and $A^2$ are not scalar matrices and we may take $B=A-A^2$ and $C=A^2$. If it is quadratic, since $A$ is not diagonalisable, the rational canonical form of $A$ must contain a $2\times2$ companion matrix $M$. Hence up to similarity we may assume that $A$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{M\\ &N}$. Take $B=\pmatrix{M\\ &N-I_{n-2}}$ and $C=\pmatrix{0\\ &I_{n-2}}$ and we are done.